# How virtual and non-virtual functions are called

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

```
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    public:
        virtual void foo();
        void foo2();
};
class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
        void foo();
        void foo2();
};
int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo;
    f->foo();         **//1**
    f->foo2();       **//2**
    return 0;
}
```

How compiler knows, 1) is dynamic in nature and 2) is static.
How both are internally called.

Comment: If I misunderstood the intention of your question, and it is more along the lines of "how does the compiler resolve which function to invoke for virtual functions" then [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103153/overloaded-virtual-function-call-resolution)

Comment: You should take a look at the [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/) FAQ on [virtual functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#overview-virtual-fns)

Comment: I have written code intentionally so to clarify doubt, 
in 1) compiler will decide using virtual table that it has to call Foo::foo as pointer is of base class
& in 2) compiler decide statically to call Foo::foo2. 
So how compiler is differentiating in both situation, after reading the statement.

Answer (score 3):

[Collected from here . . .](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#dyn-binding)

Non-virtual member functions are resolved statically. That is, the member function is selected statically (at compile-time) based on the type of the pointer (or reference) to the object.

In contrast, virtual member functions are resolved dynamically (at run-time). That is, the member function is selected dynamically (at run-time) based on the type of the object, not the type of the pointer/reference to that object. This is called “dynamic binding.” Most compilers use some variant of the following technique: if the object has one or more virtual functions, the compiler puts a hidden pointer in the object called a “virtual-pointer” or “v-pointer.” This v-pointer points to a global table called the “virtual-table” or “v-table.”

A pure virtual function is a function that must be overridden in a derived class and need not be defined. A virtual function is declared to be “pure” using the curious =0 syntax. For example:

```
class Base {
public:
    void f1();      // not virtual
    virtual void f2();  // virtual, not pure
    virtual void f3() = 0;  // pure virtual
};
Base b; // error: pure virtual f3 not overridden
```

Here, Base is an abstract class (because it has a pure virtual function), so no objects of class Base can be directly created: Base is (explicitly) meant to be a base class. For example:

```
class Derived : public Base {
    // no f1: fine
    // no f2: fine, we inherit Base::f2
    void f3();
};
Derived d;  // ok: Derived::f3 overrides Base::f3
```

***Example for Virtual or non-Virtual Fenction***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:
          virtual void NameOf();   // Virtual function.
          void InvokingClass();   //  Nonvirtual function.
          };

// Implement the two functions.
void Base::NameOf() {
    cout << "Base::NameOf\n";
   }

void Base::InvokingClass() {
    cout << "Invoked by Base\n";
   }

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
          void NameOf();   // *Virtual function*.
          void InvokingClass();   // *Nonvirtual function.*
  };

// Implement the two functions.
void Derived::NameOf() {
    cout << "Derived::NameOf\n";
 }

void Derived::InvokingClass() {
   cout << "Invoked by Derived\n";
 }
```

*Main*

```
int main() {
   // Declare an object of type Derived.
      Derived aDerived;

   // Declare two pointers, one of type Derived * and the other
   //  of type Base *, and initialize them to point to aDerived.
      Derived *pDerived = &aDerived;
      Base    *pBase    = &aDerived;

  // Call the functions.
     pBase->NameOf();           // Call virtual function.
     pBase->InvokingClass();    // Call nonvirtual function.
     pDerived->NameOf();        // Call virtual function.
     pDerived->InvokingClass(); // Call nonvirtual function.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example both `foo()` and `foo2()` will be from the `Foo` class.

```
int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo;
    f->foo();                        // Foo::foo
    f->foo2();                       // Foo::foo2
    return 0;
}
```

For you to illustrate the `virtual` behavior, you need to make an instance of the derived class

```
int main()
{
    Foo* b = new Bar;
    b->foo();                        // Bar::foo
    b->foo2();                       // Foo::foo2
    static_cast<Bar*>(b)->foo2();    // Bar::foo2
    return 0;
}
```

Notice in the latter case, since `b` is actually a `Bar`, it invokes the overriden virtual method `foo`. But since `foo2` isn't declared `virtual` and `b` is a `Foo`, it will invoke `Foo::foo2`. However, if we cast `f` to a `Bar`, it will invoke `Bar::foo2`

Answer (score 0):

virtual keyword tells compiler for dynamic binding.

To view dynamic binding in action instantiate Foo pointer with Bar object , refer below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    public:
        virtual void foo(){std::cout<<"Foo foo"<<std::endl;};
        void foo2(){std::cout<<"Foo foo2"<<std::endl;};
};
class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
        void foo(){std::cout<<"Bar foo"<<std::endl;};
        void foo2(){std::cout<<"Bar foo2"<<std::endl;};
};
int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Bar;
    f->foo();
    f->foo2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have written code intentionally so to clarify doubt, in 1) compiler will decide using virtual table that it has to call Foo::foo as pointer is of base class & in 2) compiler decide statically to call Foo::foo2. So how compiler is differentiating in both situation, after reading the statement.

Answer (score 0):

A class which declares or inherits virtual functions has something called a *vtable* which is used to look up which function to call when you invoke a virtual function. In effect, this table contains pointers to all the virtual functions in the class, something like this (pseudo-code - this may or may not compile):

```
class Foo {
    void foo_impl(){std::cout<<"Foo foo"<<std::endl;}
    struct {
        void (*foo_ptr)();
    } vtable;
    public:
        Foo(){vtable.foo_ptr = &Foo::foo_impl;}
        void foo(){vtable.foo_ptr();}
        void foo2(){std::cout<<"Foo foo2"<<std::endl;}
};
class Bar : public Foo {
    void foo_impl(){std::cout<<"Bar foo"<<std::endl;}
    public:
        Bar(){vtable.foo_ptr = &Bar::foo_impl;}
        void foo2(){std::cout<<"Bar foo2"<<std::endl;}
};
```

Thus, when you call a virtual function, the address is first looked up in the *vtable*, so if you assign a `Bar bar; Foo& foo = bar;`, then `foo.foo()` calls `Bar`'s version of `foo()` instead of `Foo`'s version.